# index out of bounds in jsp and servlet

Tags: jsp, exception, servlets, indexoutofboundsexception

type Exception report

message java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0

description The server encountered an internal error that prevented it from fulfilling this request.

root cause

```
  java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
com.ncr.UseDetails.DisplayDetails.<init>(DisplayDetails.java:20)
org.apache.jsp.Success_jsp._jspService(Success_jsp.java:72)
org.apache.jasper.runtime.HttpJspBase.service(HttpJspBase.java:70)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServletWrapper.service(JspServletWrapper.java:439)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.serviceJspFile(JspServlet.java:395)
org.apache.jasper.servlet.JspServlet.service(JspServlet.java:339)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
com.ncr.Registration.PutDetails.doPost(PutDetails.java:81)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:650)
javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:731)
org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
```

what is causing this error and how do i resolve it?

There is a form(jsp file) that has certain entries ,the servlet(let us call it A) gets these entries stores them in a database.the servlet(A) also passes these entries to an arraylist which stores them(i.e. i have defined an arraylist outside the doPost() and used its reference variable inside the doPost() to get the value of these entries in my arraylist).I have also defined a method outside the doPost() which has a return type of list and returns this arraylist.

In another class(let us call this B) i import the servlet class and use the method that i defined in the servlet class to get the arraylist.I store this arraylist in a new List object.Using this reference i capture the value of the indexes i want inside strings(this is inside the constructor of the class B i.e. the entire process of storing the arraylist of class A in a List is done inside the constructor of class B ).I have another method inside class B that gets the value of the arraylist index 0 and stores it in a string.Now finally i use this class(B) inside a jsp by importing it inside <%@ %>
and creating it's object inside<%  %> and also calling the method that gets the value of the index 0 of the arraylist. I store this value of object.method() inside a String variable. and print this variable like this hello! <%=variable %>.
There are no errors(compile time errors) in the code.

(P.S Could not post the code here because it is very lengthy.)

The class Display Details:-
     package com.ncr.UseDetails;

```
 import java.util.*;

  import com.ncr.Registration.PutDetails;

   public class DisplayDetails 
   {

    private String fName,lName,uName,pword;
    PutDetails putdetails=new PutDetails();
    List<String> catchingList=new ArrayList<String>();
    public DisplayDetails()
    {
     catchingList=putdetails.getListDetails();

      fName=catchingList.get(0);
      lName=catchingList.get(1);
      uName=catchingList.get(2);
      pword=catchingList.get(3);



    }
     public String getfirstName()
   {


     return fName;



   }

 }
```

Comment: It is difficult to follow your query, try to re-phrase it point-wise.

Comment: Please share your code around DisplayDetails.java:20

Comment: I have attached the DisplayDetails.java class.

Comment: the DisplayDetails.java class is the class B that i was referring to in my question.

Answer (score 0):

Check this

```
com.ncr.UseDetails.DisplayDetails.<init>(DisplayDetails.java:20)
```

Line number 20 in the DisplayDetails.Java, there must be an array fetch operation taking place.

The array seems to be empty. Try to do a Sysout (or Log, if you have logging enabled) and check the value on server console/log file.

EDIT: In response of the comments and code posted, try

```
 public DisplayDetails()
    {
    catchingList=putdetails.getListDetails();
    // Print the size of the list, check it on the server console.
    System.out.println(catchingList.size());

    // Because you are expecting 4 elements, check beforehand if you have indeed 4 elements.
    if(catchingList.size() >= 4) {
      fName=catchingList.get(0);
      lName=catchingList.get(1);
      uName=catchingList.get(2);
      pword=catchingList.get(3);
    }else {
     // You are not getting 4 elements, then what is there in the Array list. Lets print that on server console.
      System.out.println(catchingList);
    }
}
```

This is one way to debug, on whether you are getting what is expected.

Comment: I have attached the DisplayDetails.java class.

Comment: Added some debugging step, you could try - And check if you are getting the expected data.